# Copying files to directory whilst retaining directory structure from list

Tags: powershell

Good afternoon all,

I'm guessing this is super easy but really annoying for me; I have a text file with a list of files, in the same folders there are LOTS of other files but I only need specific ones.

```
$Filelocs = get-content "C:\Users\me\Desktop\tomove\Code\locations.txt"

Foreach ($Loc in $Filelocs){xcopy.exe $loc C:\Redacted\output /s }
```

I figured this would go through the list which is like

"C:\redacted\Policies\IT\Retracted Documents\Policy_Control0.docx"

and then move and create the folder structure in a new place and then copy the file, it doesn't.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
RGE

Comment: *"C:\Users\me\Desktop\tomove\Code\locations.txt"* holds all the files you want copied, or moved?

Comment: Are all filepathss in the text file somewhere inside the same root folder `C:\redacted` ?

Comment: [1] use `Split-Path` to get the dir structure instead of the fill path. /////  [4] use that info to build your target dir structure. ///// [3] use `mkdir` & that dir name to create the whole dir structure. ///// [4] use `Copy-Item` to copy the file to that new dir.

Comment: No the paths are not anywhere in the destination folder.

So create the directory structure first using the Split-path function and then push through that way.


"C:\Users\me\Desktop\tomove\Code\locations.txt" contains the entire path to the file in the source directory that I want to copy to a destination location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xcopy` can't know the folder structure when you explicitly pass source file path instead of a source directory. In a path like `C:\foo\bar\baz.txt` the base directory could be any of `C:\`, `C:\foo\` or `C:\foo\bar\`.

When working with a path list, you have to build the destination directory structure yourself. Resolve paths from text file to relative paths, join with destination directory, create parent directory of file and finally use PowerShell's own `Copy-Item` command to copy the file.

```
$Filelocs = Get-Content 'locations.txt'

# Base directory common to all paths specified in "locations.txt"
$CommonInputDir = 'C:\redacted\Policies'

# Where files shall be copied to
$Destination = 'C:\Redacted\output'

# Temporarily change current directory -> base directory for Resolve-Path -Relative
Push-Location $CommonInputDir

Foreach ($Loc in $Filelocs) {

    # Resolve input path relative to $CommonInputDir (current directory)  
    $RelativePath = Resolve-Path $Loc -Relative

    # Resolve full target file path and directory
    $TargetPath   = Join-Path $Destination $RelativePath
    $TargetDir    = Split-Path $TargetPath -Parent

    # Create target dir if not already exists (-Force) because Copy-Item fails 
    # if directory does not exist.
    $null = New-Item $TargetDir -ItemType Directory -Force

    # Well, copy the file
    Copy-Item -Path $loc -Destination $TargetPath
}

# Restore current directory that has been changed by Push-Location
Pop-Location
```

Possible improvements, left as an exercise:

- Automatically determine common base directory of files specified in "locations.txt". Not trivial but not too difficult.
- Make the code exception-safe. Wrap everything between `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location` in a `try{}` block and move `Pop-Location` into the `finally{}` block so the current directory will be restored even when a script-terminating error occurs. See [about_Try Catch_Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: That's outstanding! Thank you very much I really appreciate it! It worked perfectly!

Comment: My pleasure @rge_master!